Weird horror movie: a small chimp killing people, demon coming out of a hole in a white void
I have watched this movie back in 2015 where this movie contains some disturbing scenes where a voice narrates the whole movie. I only remember some of the scenes from this movie.

One where a small chimp kills its owner with a shaving knife and then kills a couple of girls staying in the same room and proceeds to mouth fuck a girl. Then later it ends its own life.
A man trapped in a white void and there is a hole in the ground there. There comes a demon-like monster from that hole and puts its thumb on his eyes and pushes till it bleeds.

I know this was a weird horror movie; once my friend gave it to me as a prank. But I completely forgot its name. Kindly help me find it. Thanks!

Sounds like Serial Ape-ist lol

How is there a ground, much less a hole in said ground, if it’s a void? A void is a completely empty space with no visible boundaries. Is he trapped in a white room, or is it more like being in space, but then suddenly there’s a hole in the nothingness and a demon clambers out?
